# Count number of allowed CPUs in a Docker container

Tags: linux, virtualization, docker, scheduling

My specific scenario is the following. I launch a docker container with a specific cpuset:

```
docker run --cpuset-cpus="0-2" # ...
```

inside that container I run a shell script as the entry point and that shell script will run `make` at some point. I would like to figure out what a good number of jobs (`-j`) would be. I could of course pass the the number of allocated CPUs through the environment, but an automatic way to detect it would be much preferred.

I know I can use `taskset -c -p $$` or `cat /proc/self/status | grep Cpus_allowed_list` to retrieve the `Cpus_allowed` for the current process, but I do not know how to retrieve the actual number of allowed CPUs. I would like to avoid parsing the output of those commands or fiddling with the `Cpus_allowed` mask, but will do it, when out of options.

Comment: `nproc` - print the number of processing units available

Comment: @Brian That was too easy.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the `nproc` shell script tool.

So it would be `-j$(nproc)` in the make command line in question.

Comment: "docker run --rm --cpus 2 debian nproc" -> 8 ?

Comment: @EvanBenn the `--cpus="2"` doesn't limit the number of processing units and is equivalent to `-cpu-period="100000" and --cpu-quota="200000"`.